# What should I do if I have to match one column with another column in excel in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I need to find out how many rows in column B match with rows of column A.

[image]

Comment: If you actually need to find the differences, you will need to sort both columns individually, then in C compare both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C1 use `=COUNTIFS(A:A,B1)` and drag down.

Then sum up col C.

This will count double matches too. i.e if B1 is found twice it will count it as 2.

If you only want to know the unique matches use `=MIN(1,COUNTIFS(A:A,B1))` instead and apply same method

Comment: Worked Fine. Now 1299 of them matched. How do i Know Which ones didn't match?

Comment: the ones that come up as 0 haven't matched. if this works for you consider accepting this answer as correct